# New to Jquery - it does not load or work at all on any browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to jQuery. I am trying to create a simple page. Using google's hosted jQuery. Based on many examples from stackoverflow, I have written this small piece of code. The change event never gets fired. I also do not see 'can not load' alert.  If I look in the firebug and expand the script tag from google it shows it as 'undefined'. I am testing locally, not using any web-server. Can anyone please point out my mistakes? Code as below:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link href="./styles/qForm.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        if (!window.jQuery) {
            alert("can not load');
        }

        $('#choice').change(function () {
                    alert('here!');
                    if($(this).val() == '0') $(this).addClass('empty');
                    else $(this).removeClass('empty')
                });

        $('#choice').change();

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="surround">
        <div id="top">
            <h3 id="title"> Enter Information </h3>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom">
             <select id="choice">
                 <option style="color: gray;" value="0" selected="selected">Select...</option>
                 <option value="1">one</option>
                 <option value="2">two</option>
                 <option value="3">three</option>
             </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That's a *really* old version of jQuery you are loading. Here's the latest `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js`.

Comment: Try `<script src="http://ajax...."`

Comment: Combine @BramVanroy's and @Blazemonger's advice - use a recent jQuery version, and load it via `http://...`.  The `//ajax...` version only works when you're running via a web server; it will fail when you're just loading local files.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a typo.

Comment: That's a terribly old version of jQuery. If you're new to developing you should be using **jQuery 1.10.2** as it's the latest version...

Comment: the version of jquery has absolutely nothing to do with this.

Comment: @KevinB I know but you still shouldn't be using 1.2.6. That would be the equivalent of riding to work in a horse and buggy.

Comment: alert("can not load'); has incorrect syntax it should either be alert("can not load"); or alert('can not load'); You can't mix double quote " with single quote '

Comment: @War10ck That still is completely irrelevant to this question. even if he was using 1.10 or 2.0.3 he'd still be having the same problem. If he upgraded to 1.10 and was following a book on 1.2.6, he's going to have far more problems. blindly suggesting someone to update jquery isn't a good idea.

Comment: @KevinB It wasn't a blind suggestion. It was a clear and straightforward suggestion. Using an old and deprecated version of any thing will lead to the OP back tomorrow posting another question. It was simply a suggestion. It's not completely irrelevant. If he's learning he should learn correctly. Otherwise, put it away and don't learn at all.

Comment: Thanks all, I am also new to stackoverflow and not sure how to credit to multiple folks at the same time. Bram Vanroy, Blazemonger , Andrés Torres- thanks for point out. What worked for me was fixing the mistakes you pointed out and wrapping it up in ready function as Tim Withers suggested!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery use, it is typical to wrap it in a "ready" function.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#choice').change(function () {
        alert('here!');
    });
});
</script>
```

This means that jQuery will wait until the page loads completely before it applies bindings.  If it tries to apply bindings to elements that don't exist yet (the page hasn't rendered those elements), it will just be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo on the quotes of the `alert` function.

```
alert("can not load');
```

The quotes must be the same. That's should be the first reason your code isn't working.

```
alert("can not load");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add http: to your script source

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<script src="//ajax...."` isn't understood by your browser when using a local file. Change this to `<script src="http://ajax...."`

Comment: @KevinB I think my solution is easier to implement.